# CCPhysicsNode in Cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, game-physics

In Cocos2d, there is a class `CCPhysicsNode`

It can add child

```
[_physicsNode addChild:mySprite];
```

Can set the position

```
_physicsNode.position = ccp(delta), _physicsNode.position.y);
```

But how do this implemented in Cocos2d-x? *(in C++)*

**Edit**

I cannot find `cocos2d::PhysicsNode` in Cocos2d-x

**P/S: I'm very new in Cocos2d & game development**

Answer (score 0):

We usually work with object pointers in c++ and we usually use set and get function instead of directly modifying the variable

```
    _physicsNode->addChild(mySprite);
    _physicsNode->setPosition(ccp(delta, _physicsNode->getPosition().y));
```

Comment: There is no `PhysicsNode` class in Cocos2d-x

Comment: what version of cocos2dx are you using? is it 3.x?

Comment: I think they change it to PhysicSprite, you can find it in extensions. [here](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/tree/v3/extensions/physics-nodes)

Comment: I cannot find a way to include `PhysicsSprite`, but I use `Node` to do it. thank anyway

Comment: Yeah.. If you're not gonna apply any physics to it, just use `Node`

Comment: @RichardSalim I need `CCPhysicsNode` and I need to apply physics to it. What to do?